# Can a transaction be committed and serialized before others previously committed?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

In this Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Non-repeatable_reads) one can read:

```
In the other strategy, as used in multiversion concurrency control, 
Transaction 2 is permitted to commit first, which provides for better 
concurrency. However, Transaction 1, which commenced prior to Transaction 2, 
must continue to operate on a past version of the database — a snapshot of the 
moment it was started. When Transaction 1 eventually tries to commit, the DBMS 
checks if the result of committing Transaction 1 would be equivalent to the 
schedule **T1, T2**. If it is, then Transaction 1 can proceed. If it cannot be 
seen to be equivalent, however, Transaction 1 must roll back with a 
serialization failure.
```

Shouldn't the last schedule be T2, T1 instead of **T1, T2** ?

I ask this because if T2 has been committed before T1 then its effects are already visible to other transactions, but those of T1 are not because T1 is not committed yet. It seems very strange if T1 once committed could appear before T2 and other transactions that committed in the meantime -- it would be like writting in the past.

But if I am wrong, that is, if it is possible for an ongoing transaction once committed to suddenly appear before others that have been committed previously, I would like someone to explain why, with a solid example if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For determining serializability between two transactions only the dependencies between their reads and writes are needed, not their commits, nor their aborts (obviously for the aborts).

So, in the example, if T1 started before T2, and T2 has been committed, but not T1 yet, then their schedule is serializable, i.e., T1 can be committed, if it is equivalent to any one of "T1 then T2" or "T2 then T1". It does not matter which committed first.

So the Wikipedia page is correct: the actual schedule must be equivalent to the serial schedule "T1 then T2" because T1 read the value before T2 wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a complicated way of saying that if T1 tries to update a row modified by T2 *after* T1 started, T1 will receive a serialization error.

The order T1, T2 means that T2's result prevails. T1 overwriting T2's result would violate that, so T1 is aborted.

Comment: So T2's result prevails because it was already committed, right?

Comment: It prevails because it was committed *after* T1 started.

Comment: Ok, so under repeatable reads, T1 is allowed to commit after T2 has committed, even though T1 read the row before T2 wrote it, as long as it does not write the same rows. Is that so?

Comment: Right. As far as I know, the only way to get a serialization error in repeatable read is by trying to write a row that somebody has updated in the meantime. Writing a row that hasn't been updated since your snapshot won't be a problem.

Comment: Laurenz, I had to unaccept your answer after I learned more about serializability. The correct answer is the one I wrote just now. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I can live with that, but I want to state that you didn't say anywhere in your question that you were talking about serializable isolation, so I assumed you were talking about repeatable read.

Comment: Fair, I forgot to mention it explicitly.